# Is it possible to activate a virtual environment from a script?

Tags: python, python-venv

It looks as though previously it was possible to activate a virtual environment within a script using...

```
activate_this_file = "/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py"
execfile(activate_this_file, dict(__file__=activate_this_file))
```

Then `activate_this.py` was removed. For a while people were using old versions of `activate_this.py`. Is this still possible or has this function been removed?

Comment: No, because you'd then need to restart (start is the better word) the correct interpreter ("activating" is merely pointing the entrypoint to another interpreter). This feels like an [xy](https://xyproblem.info) problem. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Either way I've marked a duplicate that shows how to do something close - running a Python script from another using `subprocess` using a virtualenv

Comment: Yes, this is the old answer to this question that is no longer valid.